# Actionscript - syntax error creating regular expression to find image url

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm getting Syntax errors when trying to create following regular expression

```
var find_img_url:RegExp;
find_img_url = /(http(s?):)|([/|.|\w|\s])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/gi;
```

This is a valid Regex, it works and I tested it at http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

However I get this error when compiling:  `Syntax error: expecting identifier before dot.`

**Update:** [Documentation found here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e92.html). Forward slashes delineate a regular expression literal in the same way as quotation marks delineate a string literal. The part of the regular expression within the forward slashes defines the pattern. **When including a forward slash within a regular expression that is defined by using the forward slash delineators, you must precede the forward slash with the backslash () escape character.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is not valid regex:

```
/(http(s?):)|([/|.|\w|\s])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/gi
               ^
         you need to escape this like this \/ because it is used as a delimiter in
         the regular expression.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing an `\` before `/` you need to escape that like this

```
var find_img_url:RegExp;
find_img_url = /(http(s?):)|([\/|.|\w|\s])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)/gi; 
                           // ^there
```